# Splitting equation inside curly brackets

Tags: equations, split

I'm trying to split an equation written inside curly brackets in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a \vert_{
\begin{split}
&b //
&c
\end{split}
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

but the result is:

[image]

How can I solve the problem without using commands with many strange characters?

Comment: How about `a \vert_{\substack{b\\c}}`? But that looks strange also. So what is your desired effect? Or is it as simple as `a\vert_c^b`?

Comment: Hello @TeddyvanJerry thank you very much for your answer (the first one). I believed that the \vert symbol was able to become automatically long , but this is not true.

Comment: another way 'a \vert_{ b \atop c}'

Comment: Off-topic: You should be using double-backslashes, not double-forward slashes, to induce line breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `subarray` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package).

[image]

An advantage the `subarray` environment has over the `\substack` macro is that is more straightforward to left-align the contents of the mini-array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'subarray' env.

\begin{document}
\[
a \Big\vert_{
     \begin{subarray}{l}
       b \\ c
     \end{subarray}
  }
\]
\end{document}
```